# Why does the runtime increase when moving functions to a module?

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, profiling, massiv

I can't figure out what's wrong. I created template project with stack new, add some code:

```
module Main where

import Lib
import           Data.Massiv.Array           (Sz (..), Vector)

import qualified Data.Massiv.Array           as A
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

t mul = round . (mul *) <$> getPOSIXTime
timeMillis = t 1000

area :: BBox -> Double
area (BBox (x1, y1) (x2, y2)) = (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)

sumOfAreas :: Vector A.DS BBox -> Double
sumOfAreas bboxes = A.sfoldl (\acc box -> acc + area box) 0 bboxes

main :: IO ()
main = do
    start <- timeMillis
    putStrLn $ "Start " ++ show start
    let
        bboxes = A.makeArray A.Seq (Sz 10000 * 10000) $ (\_ -> BBox (0, 0) (12, 12)) :: Vector A.DS BBox
        result = sumOfAreas bboxes
    putStrLn $ show result
    end <- timeMillis
    putStrLn $ show (end - start)
```

```
module Lib where

import           Data.Massiv.Array           (Vector)

import qualified Data.Massiv.Array           as A

type Point = (Double, Double)

data BBox =
  BBox (Point) (Point)
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This takes an average of 100ms on my hardware.

Next, I decided to move functions in `Lib` module. Updated:

```
module Main where

import Lib
import           Data.Massiv.Array           (Sz (..), Vector)

import qualified Data.Massiv.Array           as A
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

t mul = round . (mul *) <$> getPOSIXTime
timeMillis = t 1000

main :: IO ()
main = do
    start <- timeMillis
    putStrLn $ "Start " ++ show start
    let
        bboxes = A.makeArray A.Seq (Sz 10000 * 10000) $ (\_ -> BBox (0, 0) (12, 12)) :: Vector A.DS BBox
        result = sumOfAreas bboxes
    putStrLn $ show result
    end <- timeMillis
    putStrLn $ show (end - start)
```

```
module Lib where

import           Data.Massiv.Array           (Vector)

import qualified Data.Massiv.Array           as A

type Point = (Double, Double)

data BBox =
  BBox (Point) (Point)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

area :: BBox -> Double
area (BBox (x1, y1) (x2, y2)) = (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1)

sumOfAreas :: Vector A.DS BBox -> Double
sumOfAreas bboxes = A.sfoldl (\acc box -> acc + area box) 0 bboxes
```

And the runtime is now approximately 1000 ms.

cabal file looks like:

```
cabal-version: 1.12

-- This file has been generated from package.yaml by hpack version 0.35.0.
--
-- see: https://github.com/sol/hpack
-- ... info ...

source-repository head
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/githubuser/profiling

library
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
  other-modules:
      Paths_profiling
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  ghc-options: -Wall -threaded -O3
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , massiv ==1.0.1.1
    , vector ==0.12.3.1
    , array ==0.5.4.0
    , time ==1.9.3
  default-language: Haskell2010

executable profiling-exe
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_profiling
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -Wall -threaded -O3
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , massiv ==1.0.1.1
    , vector ==0.12.3.1
    , array ==0.5.4.0
    , time ==1.9.3
    , profiling
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite profiling-test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Spec.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_profiling
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -Wall -threaded -O3
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , profiling
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Stack version

```
Version 2.9.1, Git revision 409d56031b4240221d656db09b2ba476fe6bb5b1 x86_64 hpack-0.35.0
```

ghc version 9.2.4.

In fact, I encountered this behavior when I exported one function in one of the playground-project in the Main module itself.

What explains this and how to avoid it? What am I missing?

Comment: I have no idea, but perhaps you could try adding a few `{-# INLINE ... #-}` around in the `Lib` module.

Comment: I love the "I have no idea... here is an idea". @chi is too modest, the first thought in experienced people's heads would be about inlining. Try inline, try turning on optimizations (in the before and after case). Consider looking at the assembly (`-ddump-asm` or `-ddump-llvm`).

Comment: Yes, inlining helped. It happens automatically when functions are located in same module? Probably, the compiler in this case performs optimization, seeing that the BBoxes are all the same, but cannot do this without inlining?

Comment: @TrueWarg I think it relates to fusion rules. As far as I know, there is some compiler's logic like "fuse/inline things within a module but do not do it out of module boundaries". The reason for that is because inlining can speed up your program a lot, at the cost of having a higher binary size. So, apparently using the module as a boundary of optimizations is what ghc is doing. I remmeber some posts complaining about performance inestability due to things like this... but I did not understand completely whats going on.

Comment: Maybe with `sumOfAreas` in Main the compiler can see it's only used once, so there's no harm in inlining it no matter what. Whereas with it in Lib, the compiler might not automatically expose the full-implementation for cross-module inlining (it would have to *also* compile it as a standalone function, because it's exported from the module and the computer doesn't know if there are any other consumers that will want to use the compiled module). I know GHC can do some cross-module inlining though, and I didn't think it required manual inline pragmaa everywhere.

Comment: Just to double check, you are building the executable and then running that, right? Not using ghci, runhaskell, or etc?

Comment: @Ben, yes, executable.  I think you are right about fusion. I use here Boxed array (the most slow) from Massiv library and if compiller can't detect that all of BBox have the same values (BBox (0, 0) (12, 12)), it can't optimize expression to avoid unnecessary allocations and calculations (if I understood correctly).  The same effect is obtained if the boxes are different, it works slow in both cases. I decided make BBox data unboxed    and received very good performance.

In general, first of all I wanted to understand the mechanism of the compiler here and it seemed to become clearer.